# Removing a grid row from SAEF / Channel Form and saving doesn't update entry

Tags: safecracker, grid, saef

I've got a channel form which contains a grid field and I can add and edit content with no issues. The problem however is that if I remove an entire row, and then save the edit, nothing is updated. I'm returned to the entry and the row remains.

```
{exp:channel:form channel="content" return="URL_TITLE" entry_id="{segment_3}" require_entry="yes"}

    <h1>Edit: {title}</h1>
    <input type="hidden" name="structure_uri" value="{url_title}">
    <input type="hidden" name="structure_template_id" value="36">
    <input type="hidden" name="structure_parent_id" value="0">

    <input type="text" name="title" value="{title}">

    <div id="section1" class="form-container">
       <h2>Section #1</h2>
       {field:section_1}
       <a href="#" class="add_attachment">Add Attachments?</a>
       <div class="attachments">
          <h3>Section #1 Attachments</h3>
          {field:section_1_files}
       </div>
    </div>

    <input type="submit" id="save" value="Save Changes">

{/exp:channel:form}
```

Both `{field:section_1}` and `{field:section_1_files}` are the grid fields. Once I remove a row it disappears from the page and is replaced with the;

*"You have not added any rows of data yet. Add some data?"*

But saving doesn't appear to be doing anything.

Any help would be great

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be a bug that EllisLab have provided a solution for.

Add the following line to the beginning of *system/expressionengine/fieldtypes/grid/views/publish.php*:

```
<input type="hidden" name="<?=$field_id?>" value="placeholder"/>
```

Here is the source link: https://support.ellislab.com/bugs/detail/20718